# Adding arabic and english content in same cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I try to add English and Arabic content in same `pdfpcell` but its not working properly. How can I set `rundirection` RTL for Arabic text and `rundirection` LTR for English text in same cell?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this PDF: [say_peace.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/say_peace.pdf)

You'll notice that the second block consists of Arabic text (written from right to left), with one small part that isn't Arabic: `(I18N)`

[The code to create this PDF](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=205) uses a `PdfPTable` containing a `PdfPCell` of which the run direction has been changed like this:

```
cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

The constant `RUN_DIRECTION_RTL` will only change the direction of Arabic and Hebrew characters, not of Western text.

Please note that your question isn't really phrase the way it should. It's impossible for a SO reader to know what you mean by "it's not working properly." Saying "it doesn't work" on StackOverflow is considered bad taste. You need at least show what you've tried. See what others said before on StackOverflow: http://lowagie.com/doesntwork

There's even a web site http://whathaveyoutried.com/ although I like this advice better: provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hai Thanks for your support.I tried this "PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL" and it does not work for me .I want to fill one cell like  this 1. Permit  ...........تصريح .When i try with "RTL" direction digit one comes after english text like "Permit1 " .How can i sort this issue?

Comment: Aha, but that's expected behavior, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but how can i sort out this issue using this type of content format?

Comment: Is there any other object in "itextsharp" we can specify RUN_DIRECTION_RTL" and embed in PdfPCell?